# Core Data not returning correct data sometimes

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a custom object (`Data`) inheriting from `NSObject`, that needs to be persisted into core data. Hence I created a `NSManagedObject` (`Transaction`) that contains `Data`, something like this:

```
@interface Transaction (CoreDataProperties)

@property (nonatomic) BOOL m_isUploaded;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) id m_transactionData; // this is the Data class, stored under Transformable
@property (nonatomic) int64_t m_submitDateTimeEpochMilliseconds;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *m_uuid;

@end
```

I created one context and did everything related to the context on the main thread.

I made `Data` comply with `NSCoding` and `NSCopying` protocols. Also made some custom classes used in `Data` comply with `NSCoding` as well.

This is a short extract from `Data.h`:

```
@interface Data : NSObject <NSCoding, NSCopying>

@property (strong, nonatomic, nullable) HeldItem *m_heldItem;
@property (strong, nonatomic, nullable) NSDecimalNumber *m_discountAmount;
@property (strong, nonatomic, nonnull) NSMutableArray<Record *> *m_records;
@property (strong, nonatomic, nonnull) NSString *m_transactionId;
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D m_location;
@property (strong, nonatomic, nullable) NSString *m_status;

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(nonnull NSCoder *)aCoder;
- (nonnull id)initWithCoder:(nonnull NSCoder *)aDecoder;

...lots of variables/methods here...

@end
```

If I purely just do insert, there are no issues (I confirmed this by looking at the variables during `encodeWithCoder:`). Or if I do purely just reading, there aren't no issues as well.

However, if I were to insert a new `Transaction` (and `Data`) record, and search/read an existing record and modify it (`Data`), the existing record doesn't get saved, and the new record is *mostly* blank (as if new). This issue happens at *random*. I could run it 8 times before I encounter this situation.

Any idea where I might have gone wrong? I've been stuck for quite some time.

This is the part where it seems to give me the problem:

```
    // Store the existing/new data into Core Data
    Transaction *t = [MANAGER createTransaction];
    Data *data = [Data new];
    t.m_kmsTransactionData = data;

    // ...some assigning stuffs to other variables...

    // ========== if this whole section is omitted the newly created record saves fine =========
    Transaction *old = [MANAGER getTransactionFromCoreDataWithId:someOldDataIdString];
    // oldData sometimes is returning a blank object (i.e. booleans are no, objects are nil etc)
    Data *oldData = [old.m_kmsTransactionData mutableCopy];

    oldData.m_status = @"old"; // testing to see if the old record gets updated

    old.m_isUploaded = NO;
    old.m_kmsTransactionData = [oldData copy];

    // This doesn't work because oldData.m_transactionId is nil
    data.m_transactionId = [MANAGER generateNewTransactionIDBasedOn:oldData.m_transactionId];
    //===============================================

    // ... more assigning code here ....

    // Save context
    [MANAGER saveDatabase];
```

-

```
// Some helper function in some manager
- (Transaction * _Nonnull)getTransactionFromCoreDataWithId:(NSString * _Nonnull)dataId
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:[Transaction entityName]];
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;

    NSError *error;
    NSArray<Transaction *> *fetchedObjects = [self.m_coreDataStore.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSAssert(fetchedObjects != nil, @"Failed to execute %@: %@", request, error);

    if(fetchedObjects == nil || fetchedObjects.count == 0)
    {
        // error
        return nil;
    }

    for(Transaction *t in fetchedObjects)
    {
        Data *td = t.m_kmsTransactionData;
        if([td.m_salesRecordId isEqualToString:salesRecordId])
        {
            return t;
        }
    }
 return nil;
}
```

Comment: where are you saving? why is your class not a subclass of `NSManagedObject`? Are you serialising `Data` into `Transaction` instances?

Comment: My `Data` was already created as `NSObject`, and since I need to store the `Data` so that it persists and also keep track of what I've done to `Data`, I created `Transaction` to store them. I'm saving at the end of everything. Let me correct the code.

Comment: Can you enable CD debug "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1" under Arguments Passed on Launch. I wonder if CD automatically uses NSKeyedArchiver to pack/unpack your object.

Comment: Enabled it and I didn't see anything like that in the console. I think the debug thing was helpful I think i found my problem - logic error afterall. Need to test and confirm, will close question once done

Comment: Looks like it is fixed. I still don't understand why it worked sometimes when it shouldn't even work at all. I will figure it out next Monday. My brain's super fried right now

Comment: Advice: clean up your variable names to make them more human readable.

Comment: Thanks, I changed some of them just to post the code on here, but I agree some could and should be named better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it was a Core Data quirk with transformable properties but it wasn't.

The part where I was

```
// ...some assigning stuffs to other variables...
```

I assigned `m_salesRecordId` to an existing id, which was already inside the database. So while searching through the `getTransactionFromCoreDataWithId:` method, it returned the newly created object based on the `m_salesRecordId` I've just made earlier.

As for why it worked sometimes and it didn't work sometimes was because the fetched query results wasn't sorted (I assume the order in which the results are returned are always not in sequence), so whichever record was returned first got returned as the searched object (which could either be the empty object I just created or the actual object that was already inside).

I still could not understand yet as to why even though the `m_salesRecordId` was nil after the screwup, the rest of the variables in the object could not be saved. But since everything is working as intended I'll take the win for now.

tl;dr:
Check your program logic again first